# Cmd+I does not work in Java Perspective in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, hotkeys

I'm using Eclipse 4.4.1 on Mac OS X 10.10.2. Menu File > Properties has a hotkey <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>.  But pressing that does not bring up the same window showing the properties of the .java file open in the editor window.  Any ideas?

BTW, do people have a sense if SO is any better than than https://eclipse.org/forums/ for getting quick replies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Java editor Cmd+I is bound to the 'Correct Indentation' command, this takes precedence over the Properties binding when you are in the editor.

Look in 'Preferences > General > Keys' to see the key bindings. Click on the 'Binding' column to sort by the key binding to see all the bindings for a key together.